# Git - master change, rebase onto complex branches?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

So I have a complex local branch structure: my main working local branch, and two other branches off of it.  There was a new change in master that I want in my branches.  What is the best way to propagate it to all of my branches? Is rebasing possible?

```
A---E---M  master 
     \ 
      F---G---H  local_branch_main
          |\ 
          | I---J  local_subbranch_1
           \K---L  local_subbranch_2
```

Ideally, I'd want to just move all the branches to reference off of the new master commit (there are no conflicts):

```
A---E---M  master 
         \ 
          F---G---H  local_branch_main
              |\ 
              | I---J  local_subbranch_1
               \K---L  local_subbranch_2
```

Comment: Without knowing what you branch update strategy is or how many developers have local copies of those branches it is impossible to even guess.

Comment: @AndrewC: This is all local, with the exception of commit M.  But I can make everyone accept whatever history I come up with.

Comment: @Tonio, that looks promising but I get the following error:
fatal: no such branch: *
error: could not apply C... <C's commit message>

Comment: In that case just start with main and rebase, then do the two sub-branches. `git rebase --onto SHA`

Comment: If I do that, I get the subbranches pointing to the old non-rebased commits as in the link Tonio suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

First do

```
git checkout local_branch_main
git rebase master
```

If you are lucky and you don't have any conflicts your repository will now look like this:

```
A---E---M  master 
    \    \ 
     \    F'---G---H  local_branch_main
      F
      |\ 
      | I---J  local_subbranch_1
       \K---L  local_subbranch_2
```

Now here comes the interessting part. As you can see the commit `F` and `F'` contains the same changes (if there were no conflicts), but `F'` has another parent commit and another commit id. I make this visible by naming it `F'`.

So now you can switch to branch `local_subbranch_1` and rebase it on  `F'`

```
git checkout local_subbranch_1
git rebase F'
```

of course you must replase `F'` with the commit id of `F'`

Now your repository looks like this

```
   A---E---M  master 
       \    \ 
        \    F'---G---H  local_branch_main
        F     \ 
         \     I---J  local_subbranch_1
          \
           K---L  local_subbranch_2
```

Finally you can checkout `local_subbranch_2` and rebase it on `F'` and your repository will look like

```
   A---E---M  master 
            \ 
             F'---G---H  local_branch_main
             |\ 
             | I---J  local_subbranch_1
             \
               K---L  local_subbranch_2
```

I have created a demo repository that you can download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftro2ccct4n5r55/SO_26537814.zip?dl=0). You can replay the steps above on it.